# Deserialing an object with unknown properties

Tags: json, serialization, dictionary

I have the following JSON string:

```
    {
    "id": "0",
    "version": "1.1",
    "result": {
        "status": "{\"1\": \"CONTINUOUS\", \"3\": \"NOT_CONFIGURED\", \"2\": \"NOT_CONFIGURED\", \"4\": \"EVENTO\"}"
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize this string to a c# class. First of all, I used json2csharp.com, and I get these c# classes to deserialize the string:

```
public class Result {
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

This solution is not valid for me because status is not a string, it is a Dictionary object. The keys and valus of this dictionary and not fixed, could be different.

My workaround:

I add a method in Result class to get that dictionary, but I realize that this workaround in not very "pretty", I am sure someone can get me a better solution.
Class with the method:

```
public class Result {
     public string status { get; set; }
     public Dictionary < string, string > GetValues() {
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary < string, string >> (status);
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks not like valid JSON - rather like nested JSON or something like that. You can't deserialize this in one go like you already acknowledged. Are you able to fix the JSON string so you don't need to work your way around it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here would be:

How to obtain a dictionary from the string:

```
"status": "{\"1\": \"CONTINUOUS\", \"3\": \"NOT_CONFIGURED\", \"2\": \"NOT_CONFIGURED\", \"4\": \"EVENTO\"}"
```

You know that `status` key "points" to a value of type string and that string is formated as a dictioary. You also know a dictionary is  `{` - sequence of `key:values` pairs - `}`.

The only problem remains is the type of keys and values. If your keys and values are always the same type (lets say, integer and string as in the example) well, problem solved.

Just parse `status` string into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that I have included the GetValues method in Result class because if I put the status property as Dictionary does not works.

JsonSerializationException
Error converting value "{"1": "CONTINUOUS", "3": "NOT_CONFIGURED", "2": "NOT_CONFIGURED", "4": "NOT_CONFIGURED"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path 'result.status', line 1, position 157.
+       InnerException  {"Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}